# Ionic 2, Angular 2 Textbox values in For Loop

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Ionic 2 and Angular 2

I have 3 textboxes each one with different ngModel value 
Home.html file:

```
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Off Peak Usage1:</ion-label>     
   <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="usage.usage1"></ion-input> 
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Off Peak Usage2:</ion-label>     
   <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="usage.usage2"></ion-input>   
 </ion-item>
 <ion-item>
   <ion-label>Off Peak Usage3:</ion-label>     
   <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="usage.usage3"></ion-input> 
 </ion-item>
```

I want to do some calculation part on those entered values in textboxes one after other. I want each text box value must be passed one after other. Below is my For loop in 
Home.ts file:

```
usage={
    usage1:'',
    usage2:'',
    usage3:''
};
for(let i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
    let total_usage = this.usage.usage[i];
    let total = total_usage * 5;
}
```

I am getting usage not defined on `this.usage.usage[i]`

I don't know I am doing correctly or not, can any one help me out with this ?

Thank you.

Comment: `this.usage.usage[i]` you have three _different_ properties `usage1,usage2,usage3` not an array of `usage`.

Comment: @suraj thank you. so how can use those property values in an array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to access object property like so:

```
this.usage['usage1']
```

Your loop will be:

```
for(let i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
    let total_usage = this.usage['usage'+i];
    let total = total_usage * 5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. Thank you so much for your quick reply.